# Unsigned long int make a variable equal to 0

Tags: c, type-conversion

I have the following code which should compute the factorial of a given number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   unsigned short int n, i;
   unsigned long int fact=1;

   printf("Give n:");
   scanf("%u", &n);
   printf("\nfact=%u", fact);

   for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        fact = fact * i;

   printf("\n%u!=%u", n, fact);
   return 0;
}
```

I have tried to check what is the problem and found that variable fact is 0.
Can somebody explain to me why variable fact is 0 since I have initialized it with 1?
If it have any importance, I use GNU GCC compiler in Codeblocks.

Comment: Why are you using `unsigned short` anyway? And you'd probably be better using `unsigned long long fact`.

Comment: `%lu` for long unsigned and `%hu` for short unsigned

Comment: I have modified `%u` in `%hu` and surprisingly for me, the program works. Now variable `fact` is `1`. Now I am more confused. This change I have made for the variable `n`, but also variable `fact` is affected. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using GCC, you should be using `-Wall` as an option, which tells you exactly what the problem is:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:9:4: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘short unsigned int *’ [-Wformat=]
    scanf("%u", &n);
    ^
```

You're telling it to read a value into `unsigned int` variable, but you're giving a pointer to an `unsigned short`, which is smaller, so it overwrites whatever is after `n` in the stack frame, causing undefined behavior -- in your case, corrupting `fact`.

Moral: Always use `-Wall` to enable warnings, and pay attention to them...

Comment: I didn't know about the `-Wall` option; now I have activated it.
Thanks for this advice and for the explanation about the error; among many others, I have a lack in understanding what happens inside the computer memory.